# Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors while using it inside a loop for forecasting

Tags: r, arima, forecast

I am using the "$" operator to get the predicted values and the model used by combining `stlf` and `auto.arima` functions. 
This code is working properly for a different dataset, but here it is giving me this error.

I have tried replacing `$` with `[[ ]]`, but that's also resulting to the same error. 
Train_df is a time series with 41 rows and 5 columns. Each column is a different product data.

```
Train_df <- ts(Train_df, start=c(2000,1), frequency =12)
fcast <- matrix(NA,nrow=10,ncol=ncol(Train_df))
model <- matrix(NA, nrow = 2, ncol = ncol(Train_df))
colnames(model) <- colnames(Train_df)
acc <- matrix(NA, nrow=ncol(Train_df), ncol=5)
colnames(acc) <- c("ME","RMSE","MAE","MPE","MAPE")

# Combining two models
for(i in 1:ncol(Train_df)){
  fc1 <- forecast(stlf(Train_df[,i],h=10)) #forecast using stlf function
  fc2 <- forecast(auto.arima(Train_df[,i]),h=10) #forecast using auto.arima function
  fcast[,i] <- 0.5*(fc1$mean+fc2$mean) #combining the values from both the forecasts
  model[1,i] <- fc1$method
  model[2,i] <- fc2$method
  acc[i,] <- accuracy(fcast[,i],Test_df[,i]) #Testing for accuracy
}
```

This code is resulting ot the following error.
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.

Can someone suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: You should be able to first try stepping through your code by setting `i=1`, then run through it step by step. Then set `i=2` and repeat. That might find the error given it will be tough to create an example given the complexity of your data. Maybe add in a dummy dataset with 5 rows and columns of random numbers so we can reproduce?

Comment: What is the structure of `fc1` ?

Comment: fc1 is a forecast object. ```List of 10
 $ mean     : Time-Series [1:10] from 2017 to 2018: 8628 7755 7136 3967 7625 ...
 $ method   : chr "STL +  ETS(A,N,N)"
 $ series   : chr "df_new[, i]"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "forecast"```

Comment: @JackArmstrong :I tried stepping it and for each iteration, the code is producimg same error.

Comment: Which line did it occur because that is where you are going wrong. Then compare the structures of each bit, using `str()`.

Comment: It is occuring at the first instance when $ is used. This same code is working fine on another dataset. I also tried running it on different datasets. It is working on some of them, on others it is giving an error. When does such a situation arise?

Comment: Could you post a dput(head(Train_df))?